# Chromatic index of complete graph $K_n$ after removing one edge

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I really don't know how to deal with it.

I know that for $K_n$:

- $n$ even: we have chromatic index $n-1$
- $n$ odd: we have chromatic index $n$

But how to prove and get the answer after removing one edge?
I assume that it's still the same answer but don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard case is $n$ odd. Let us write the resulting graph from removing an edge from $K_n$, as $H_n$. Then the chromatic index of $H_n$ is still exactly $n$.

To see this, first note the following: if $H_n$ had chromatic index $n-1$ or smaller, then it would be possible to partition the edge-set of $H_n$ into $n-1$ matchings. We claim this is impossible. Indeed, as $n$ is odd,  each matching in $H_n$ has at most $\frac{n-1}{2}$ edges [make sure you see why]. Thus, if it were possible to partition the edge-set of $H_n$ into at most $n-1$ matchings, the graph $H_n$ would have at most $(n-1)×\frac{n-1}{2}$ edges. However, $H_n$ has $\left(n×\frac{n-1}{2}\right)-1$ $>$ $(n-1)×\frac{n-1}{2}$ edges, so it is indeed impossible to partition the edge-set of $H_n$ into $n-1$ or fewer matchings after all. Thus the chromatic index of $H_n$ is at least $n$.

As the chromatic index of $K_n$ is exactly $n$ however, and $H_n$ is a subgraph of $K_n$, it follows that the chromatic index of $H_n$ cannot be any larger than $n$ as well, and so from the previous paragraph it must be exactly $n$.

Can you handle the case for $n$ even? HINT: For $n \ge 4$ note that removing an edge from $K_n$ does not change the minimum degree, it still remains $n-1$ ...